# Git authentication over https on owned server

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, server

I am going to start a project on my company where we are going to use git as scm. 
I havent been able to find any good tutorials on how to set up the git server on https hosted on a private server, not github or such.

Where should I configure the usernames and passwords to let them access to the git server?

Do I need apache or any other web server installed as well?

How do I grant for certain users only pull but not push?

Do you recommend to use ssh over https? If so, any good links you can share on the matter for installation and configuration purposes would be gladly appreciated.

I know these are a lot of questions but havent been able to find something relevant on the topic. The [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) is on ssh.

Comment: I recommend setting up a custom gitlab server, it's easier and has better documentation, see here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: did you check [bonobo](https://bonobogitserver.com/)

Answer (score 0):

As @ProNinjaCat mentioned, it is probably easiest to set up [Gitlab](http://about.gitlab.com/). It will let you use both ssh and https and handles all of the administrative tasks for you.

Comment: What about if I will have a windows server? As I saw there is no possibility to install it in windows...by the way gitlab would be a owned github on a owned server?

Comment: Perhaps  you could run it in a docker image then: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html  Yes, you own/control the installation.